# How to use groupby and do iterative operation on dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I know it sounds like a very simple problem but i am struggling to get the proper solution for this, I have a input dataframe, where i want to add a new column `derived` based on `area` group and simple arithmetic operation between `amount` and `rate`. I know i have to run aloop for each row to get the previous derived value to calculate next derived value:

[image]

Output dataframe (added some comments in :

[image]

I am trying something like this:

```
def func(df):
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        return (df['derived'].shift(1) * df['rate'])

df['derived'] = df['amount']
df['derived'] =  df.groupby(['area']).apply(func)
```

But getting error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'
```

Comment: please provide reproducible input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `groupby.cumprod` with custom groups:

```
m = df['rate'].isna()

df['derived'] = df['amount'].where(m, df['rate']).groupby(m.cumsum()).cumprod()
```

output: None provided as the data is not reproducible

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy dataframe. Does this work on your data?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"amount":[100,200,250,1002,3040,5000,10200,15489],
              "rate":[None, 0.8,0.9,0.3,0.4,None,0.23,0.8]})

df = df.ffill().fillna(1)

df["derived"] = df.apply(lambda x: (np.where(x.name==0, x.amount * x.rate,
                            x.amount + df.shift(1).loc[x.name].amount) * x.rate), 
                     axis=1)
```